# importlib.metadata error on pre-commit tool

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, asdf

I have installed pre-commit 3.0.1 via asdf. When I try to run pre-commit -v throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/san/.cache/pre-commit-zipapp/6Bkef3U7os33XPapd4VZ7HEfyUexbeBTjOn51afz0r8/python", line 47, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(main())
  File "/Users/san/.cache/pre-commit-zipapp/6Bkef3U7os33XPapd4VZ7HEfyUexbeBTjOn51afz0r8/python", line 34, in main
    runpy.run_module(args.m, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/Users/san/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/Users/san/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Users/san/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/san/.cache/pre-commit-zipapp/6Bkef3U7os33XPapd4VZ7HEfyUexbeBTjOn51afz0r8/wheels/pre_commit-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pre_commit/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    
  File "/Users/san/.cache/pre-commit-zipapp/6Bkef3U7os33XPapd4VZ7HEfyUexbeBTjOn51afz0r8/wheels/pre_commit-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pre_commit/main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/san/.cache/pre-commit-zipapp/6Bkef3U7os33XPapd4VZ7HEfyUexbeBTjOn51afz0r8/wheels/pre_commit-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pre_commit/constants.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'
```

Python version: **3.7.9**

asdf version: **v0.11.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the python to version 3.8.7 solved the issue, since for the pre-commit minimum required Python version is 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

you've forced the installation of pre-commit 3.x to a version which it does not support

pre-commit is python3.8+ only (it uses `python_requires>=3.8` in the metadata).  pip refuses to install the version on older python's so somehow you've bypassed that safeguard

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Answer (score 0):

Pre-commit's [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/pre-commit/) states that the minimum required Python version is 3.8.

`Requires: Python >=3.8`

[image: Screenshot of pre-commit PyPi page]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use python version under 3.8, install version 4.x of importlib-metadata.

Example work with me: python `3.7.10` and `importlib-metadata == 4.10.0`